# Is front face tracking really NOT supported in a world tracking AR session (ARWorldTrackingConfiguration) on iPad Pro 2020? Edited with answer

Tags: ipad, arkit

I'm developing an app that requires use of the front-facing (TrueDepth) face tracking capabilities in an ARKit world tracking session configuration. This functionality (using the front and back cameras simultaneously in ARKit) has worked wonderfully since it was introduced with ARKit 3 last summer...on my iPhones with TrueDepth cameras. I received my new iPad Pro 2020 today, fired up my app, and was shocked to discover that `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsUserFaceTracking` returns false. This almost cannot be the case as it dramatically defeats the purpose of the device, which is to enable next-generation AR experiences. I've verified this with Apple's own demo app "Combining User Face-Tracking and World Tracking", which doesn't run on the iPad Pro. I have also verified that face tracking does work in the `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`.

Can anyone explain this or offer a workaround or solution? It seems impossible that this crucial functionality isn't supported on this particular device.

ANSWER: Confirmed by Apple - this is a hardware issue with iPad Pro. Due to LiDAR hardware configuration, the device can't support using front and back cameras simultaneously at all.